# Vuetify combined navigation drawers

Tags: vue.js, mobile, vuetify.js

I'm currently trying to implement combined navigation drawers in a project.
My issue is when I try to adapt to mobile. Meaning that if I use the "normal" way of show/hide I can't keep the left navigation drawer (small and nice on mobile) and toggle the other.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/3r87152u/

```
<v-navigation-drawer
    v-model="drawer"
    disable-resize-watcher
    width="100%"
  >
    <v-row class="fill-height" no-gutters>
      <v-navigation-drawer
        dark
        mini-variant
        mini-variant-width="56"
        permanent
      >
```

I would like to be able to, when in mobile, hide the navigation drawer of the right side and keep the other. Since the navigation drawer of the left side is inside of the right one, I'm completely lost. Is there a way of doing that? Thank you for trying to help!